# Get pull request info on trigger with multiple VCS roots

Tags: git, github, sonarqube, teamcity

I have a TeamCity (version 2017.2.4) project with multiple configurations which are attached to various GitHub repositories. Now I would like to setup [SonarQube GitHub plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) for some of these configurations. To do so, I've created a new build and attached a `VCS Trigger`. In order to make this trigger work, I also attached all VCS roots which I'd like this build to run on. Now after any changes in these VCS roots, the build gets triggered.

In order to use this plugin, after each trigger I need to extract repository name which was affected and fetch the pull request id. This is easy to do if I have a single VCS root with the following script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit script on any command failure.
set -e

# Pass parameter to next TeamCity build step.
param() {
    echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='$1' value='$2']"
}

# Full GitHub repository name.
repository="myOrg/$(echo '%vcsroot.url%' | grep -oP '(?<=\/).*(?=\.git)')"

# Full URL to fetch branch pull request info.
url="https://api.github.com/repos/${repository}/pulls"
url="${url}?head=%teamcity.build.branch%"
url="${url}&access_token=%github.authToken%"

echo "Fetching PR information from: ${url}"
res=$(curl "${url}" -f)

echo "Parsing PR id from:"
echo "${res}"
pullRequest=$(echo "${res}" | grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=pulls\/)\d+(?=",)')

if [ -z "${pullRequest}" ]; then
    echo "Could not parse PR id from: ${res}"
    exit 1
fi

# Pass parameters to next build step which will init the plugin.
param 'github.pullRequest' ${pullRequest}
param 'github.repository' ${repository}
```

However since I have multiple VCS roots, I'm not able to refer to `%vcsroot.url%`, so:

- How could I get this information with my current setup?
- Are there any other ways of setting up a build so that I could get branch name and pull request id (note I'm looking for a way to do this with only one build configuration)?

Comment: If your "normal" build configurations have one single VCS Root, instead of having a separate build configuration with multiple VCS root for SonarQube, consider implementing SonarQube scan as a build step in a (parametrized) template, and then attach your existing build configurations to that template. This way the SonarQube build step inherited from the template will only see one VCS Root of the currently triggered build config.